# MySQL get the nearest future date to given date, from the dates located in different table having Common ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables - Client and Banquet

```
Client Table
----------------------------
ID     NAME
1      John
2      Jigar
3      Jiten

----------------------------
Banquet Table
----------------------------
ID     CLIENT_ID   DATED    
1      1           2016.2.3
2      2           2016.2.5
3      2           2016.2.8
4      3           2016.2.6
5      1           2016.2.9
6      2           2016.2.5
7      2           2016.2.8
8      3           2016.2.6
9      1           2016.2.7

----------------------------
:::::::::: **Required Result**
----------------------------
ID     NAME          DATED
2      Jigar         2016.2.5
3      Jiten         2016.2.6
1      John          2016.2.7
```

> The result to be generated is such that
>
> > **1.** The Date which is FUTURE : CLOSEST or EQUAL to the current date, which is further related to the respective client should be filtered and ordered in format given in **Required Result**
>
> CURDATE() for current case is 5.2.2016

**FAILED: Query Logic 1**

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, b.dated
FROM client AS c, banquet AS b
WHERE c.id = b.client_id AND b.dated >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY (b.dated - CURDATE());

------------------------------------------- OUTPUT
ID     NAME          DATED
2      Jigar         2016.2.5
2      Jigar         2016.2.5
3      Jiten         2016.2.6
3      Jiten         2016.2.6
1      John          2016.2.7
2      Jigar         2016.2.8
2      Jigar         2016.2.8
1      John          2016.2.9
```

**FAILED: Query Logic 2**

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, b.dated
FROM client AS c, banquet AS b
   WHERE b.dated = (
       SELECT MIN(b.dated)
       FROM banquet as b
       WHERE b.client_id = c.id
           AND b.dated >= CURDATE()
   )
ORDER BY (b.dated - CURDATE());

------------------------------------------- OUTPUT
ID     NAME          DATED
2      Jigar         2016.2.5
2      Jigar         2016.2.5
3      Jiten         2016.2.6
3      Jiten         2016.2.6
1      John          2016.2.7
```

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aded8/1)

> **UPDATE** : Further result to be generated is such that
>
> > **2.** Clients WITHOUT : DATED should also be listed : may be with a NULL
> >
> > **3.** the information other then DATED in the BANQUET table also need to be listed

**UPDATED Required Result**

```
ID     NAME          DATED        MEAL
2      Jigar         2016.2.5     lunch
3      Jiten         2016.2.6     breakfast
1      John          2016.2.7     dinner
4      Junior        -            -
5      Master        -            supper
```

Comment: where does 'meal' come from? given that you changed your question significantly after it had been answered, you might want to post a separate question for the 'NULL' cases and 'meal' component.

Comment: @Stidgeon I was also confused that should i ask this in the same question or in  an new question. But now i think new question is a good way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query, I suggest applying your `WHERE` condition `>= CURDATE()` and then `SELECT` the `MIN(dated)` with `GROUP BY client_id`:

```
SELECT b.client_id, MIN(b.dated) FROM banquet b
WHERE b.dated >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY b.client_id;
```

From this, you can add the necessary `JOIN` to the client table to get the client name:

```
SELECT b.client_id, c.name, MIN(b.dated) FROM banquet b
INNER JOIN client c
ON c.id = b.client_id
WHERE b.dated >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY b.client_id;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aded8/18

EDITED TO REFLECT NEW PARTS OF QUESTION:

Based on the new info you added - asking how to handle nulls and the 'meal' column, I've made some changes. This updated query handles possible null values (by adjusting the WHERE clause) in dated, and also includes meal information.

```
SELECT b.client_id, c.name, 
MIN(b.dated) AS dated,
IFNULL(b.meal, '-') AS meal
FROM banquet b
INNER JOIN client c
ON c.id = b.client_id
WHERE b.dated >= CURDATE() OR b.dated IS NULL
GROUP BY b.client_id;
```

or you can take some of this and combine it with Gordon Linoff's answer, which sounds like it will perform better overall.

New SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4055/2

Comment: it works great, and on that it is also able to get any fields form both the tables by just mentioning in the `SELECT`. But it is not able to give `CLIENTS` with the `BANQUET.DATED` havin `NULL`. Well it was not my initial question, but i improved and updated the question for the same.

Answer (score 2):

One approach uses a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*,
       (select max(dated)
        from banquet b
        where b.client_id = c.id and
              b.dated >= CURDATE()
       ) as dated
from client c;
```

Then, I would recommend an index on `banquet(client_id, dated)`.

The advantage of this approach is performance.  It does not require an aggregation over the entire client table.  In fact, the correlated subquery can take advantage of the index, so the query should have good performance.

Comment: its working awesome when only `banquet.dated` is to be taken as output from `banquet`. But when i tried to get `banquet.meal` also for the output it does not work. Well it was not my initial question but i updated the question for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT banquet.client_id, MIN(banquet.dated) 
FROM banquet 
WHERE banquet.dated >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY banquet.client_id;
```

if you want to limited output like your expected result is 3 record so you can use `limit` in this case

```
SELECT banquet.client_id, MIN(banquet.dated) 
FROM banquet 
WHERE banquet.dated >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY banquet.client_id limit 3;
```

if you want to use join with `Client` table you can use `join'

```
SELECT banquet.client_id, MIN(banquet.dated) 
FROM banquet JOIN Client 
ON Client.id = banquet.client_id
WHERE banquet.dated >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY banquet.client_id;
```

also use `limit` with last query.

Answer (score 1):

> The Date which is CLOSEST or EQUAL to the current date

To closely rspond to your requirements, i. e. "CLOSEST" may be both *before or after* the current date, the query must use the (absolute) difference between it and the `DATED` value.

So it can be achieved like this:

```
SELECT 
  c.id, c.name, b.dated,
  MIN(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, b.dated, CURDATE()))) AS `delta`
FROM banquet AS b
  INNER JOIN client AS c ON b.client_id = c.id
GROUP BY b.client_id
```

Here is the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aded8/27/1)

Comment: @Stidgeon Yes, now I see that. But the question has been modified, just adding "future" (look at edit 1), probably when the OP read my answer and realized that the question was ambiguous.

Comment: @cFreed also this was not my exact question still it helped me for my other query hence upvoted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try :
ORDER BY (ABS(DATEDIFF(row_date, NOW())) AND row_date>=NOW()) DESC

Comment: To make this answer more useful to readers of this question, consider adding a description to explain what you're doing.